# Video player with caption automatically generated from the audio

Tags: osx, media-player, speech-recognition

I'm looking for a **audio/video player** with caption automatically generated from the audio track (speech to text). The speech recognition doesn't need to be perfect, I want it so I can skip the boring part but getting a quick idea of the subject.

Would be nice to be able to change the speed but keeping same sound pitch.

In term of features, a good example is the player used on the edx.org website:
[image: Player from edx.org]

Comment: Must it be free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: Don't need to be free.